# How to compile and run a project from a separate folder?

Tags: java

I just write a simple project that do sum of two numbers  .My project lacate at 3 seprate folder  :

1-Operator interface(e:\operator)

```
package operator;

public interface Operator
{
    int claculate(int firstNumber,int secondNumber);

}
```

2-class plus that implements Operator(e:\operation)  :

```
package operation;

import operator.*;

public class Plus implements Operator
{   
    public int claculate(int firstNumber,int secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
```

3-main project(e:\main)

```
package main;
import operator.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Sum
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 7;

        Operator instance;
        Class cls;

        instnace = (Operator)cls.newInstance();
        int output = instance.calculate(num1,num2);
        System.out.println("your result is :" + output);
    }
}
```

Now when I compile this 3 folder together like so  :
javac main/*.java operation/*.java operator/*.java 
I got this error  :can not find symbol instance 
How should I import this three folder that have dependency and compile them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you have a typo, because you call `instnace` and declared variable is `instance` (*so I suppose that is the cause of your compilation error*)

Then, you have to compile first operator, then compile Plus adding operator to the classpath, and finally the last one adding both Operator and Plus to the classpath.

You add the classpath this way

```
javac -cp directory_with_clases your_java.java
```

But instead, I think it is worth to say that maven will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `Operator instance;` instead of `Operator instnace` 
May be its typo. But its not the way you need to finally call a interface method. 
Simpler this way

```
import operation.*;

Operator instance = new Plus ();
```